# Can't open a SqLiteConnection with asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, database-connection

I'm trying to use SQLite with asp.net core 3.1
I installed the MS Data SQLite Core nuget package.

When I don't specify the version in the connection string, the server version variable in the SQLiteConnection is null and I got this error :

> System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

But when I specify the version, it says that the keyword Version is not supported...
Maybe it's an antother problem?

My code :

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
{
    DataSource = "./MyTestDB.db",
    Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
    Password = "Toto",
}.ToString();

using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

PS : I tried full path too...

Thanks in advance for reading this. I didn't found the answer after research..

Comment: Why are you constructing it with a connection string and also with object intialization?

Comment: Also, what does `ToString()` give you? You should be using the `ConnectionString` property, not `ToString()`.

Comment: @Crowcoder `ToString()` does [return the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.tostring)

Comment: I think you are mixing System.Data and Microsoft.Data namespaces. Try fully qualifying the builder and connection with `Microsoft.Data`. There is no `Version` key in Microsoft.Data.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping me.
I still have the same error when I only have :

                using (var connection = new Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection("Data Source=./MyDB.db"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

I don't see the mistake -_-'

Comment: +  ServerVersion 'connection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' string {System.NullReferenceException}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. SQLite "standart" has no encryption. The problem was password. I took it off and then it worked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my connection problem by changing Microsoft.Data.SQLite.Core package by System.Data.SQLite.Core.
It works now, but that still doesn't explain why the MS one doesn't work with me..

Answer (score 0):

For the the problem was I had included `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` instead of `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` (note the lack of `.Core`).